MS Excel 2016 ActiveX Toolbox
Good morning experts.
Our company creates macro enabled spreadsheet tools using VBA and controls from the ActiveX toolbox. There are some developers who use shapes vs. command buttons to trigger subs and functions. There have been issues with the ActiveX controls not working as expected unless the 'Optimize for compatibility' setting is selected in the Excel Options. I saw some things online that ActiveX has been deprecated, but that is within browsers. Does anyone know if the controls in the ActiveX toolbox in the Desktop versions of the Office tools (specifically Excel) have also been deprecated? What buttons do people on the form primarily use?
Thank you in advance, Wheels
We tried using shapes, ActiveX controls, and RibbonX controls to trigger code.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/enable-or-disable-activex-settings-in-office-files-f1303e08-a3f8-41c5-a17e-b0b8898743ed
